How to get column and row percent when using tbl_summary in R?
I am attempting to create a descriptive table using tbl_summary in R that will show both the column percentage and the row percentage for each category. Consider the following example code using the iris R dataset:
iris_table <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length.Cat = if_else(Sepal.Length > 5, "Big","Small")) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              include = c(Sepal.Length.Cat, Sepal.Width),
              type = list(
                Sepal.Width ~ "continuous2"
              ),
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous2() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})","{min} - {max}"),
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"
              ),
              missing_text = "Missing") %>% 
  add_overall(col_label = "**Overall** <br>N = {n}") %>% 
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA)
print(iris_table)

Using the above code, I get the default output for the {p} argument, which is percent = "column". However, I would also like to include a row percent. For example, n = 22 in the cell for Setosa species with "Big" sepal length. Right now, the cell is showing 22 (44%), which 22 / 50 Setosa total. I would like for it to show something like "n = 22 (44%; 19%)", with the 19% being the additional row percent (i.e., 22/ 118 total Big).
I have attempted using the percent = "row" argument that is built into tbl_summary. However, that not only gets rid of the column percent, but it also changes the percents in the Overall column to be row percents as well. I would like the column percents to stay and the Overall category to remain just column percents.

The package wasn't designed to show both row and column percentages. But in the new version of the package, there are more generalizable ways to create bespoke tables. In the example below, we first calculate all the statistics that will appear in the table, then pass them to a new function called tbl_ard_summary(). It's not the easiest code to read, but it does get you both percentage.
library(cards)
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '2.0.1.9002'

iris2 <- iris |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Sepal.Length.Cat = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, "Big","Small"))

# create the primary ARD
ard <- iris2 |>
  ard_stack(
    .by = Species,
    ard_continuous(variables = Sepal.Width),
    ard_categorical(variables = Sepal.Length.Cat),
    .missing = TRUE,
    .attributes = TRUE
  ) |> 
  # create ARD for row percentages
  bind_ard(
    ard_categorical(iris2, by = Species, variables = Sepal.Length.Cat, statistic = ~"p", denominator = "row") |> 
      dplyr::mutate(stat_name = ifelse(stat_name == "p", "p_row", stat_name))
  )


# pass the ARD to gtsummary to create table
ard |> 
  tbl_ard_summary(
    by = Species,
    include = c(Sepal.Length.Cat, Sepal.Width),
    type = list(
      Sepal.Width ~ "continuous2"
    ),
    statistic = list(
      all_continuous2() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})","{min} - {max}"),
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} (Column {p}%; Row {p_row}%)"
    ),
    missing_text = "Missing"
  ) |> 
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO




Characteristic
setosa
versicolor
virginica




Sepal.Length.Cat





Big
22 (Column 44.0%; Row 18.6%)
47 (Column 94.0%; Row 39.8%)
49 (Column 98.0%; Row 41.5%)


Small
28 (Column 56.0%; Row 87.5%)
3 (Column 6.0%; Row 9.4%)
1 (Column 2.0%; Row 3.1%)


Sepal.Width





Mean (SD)
3.4 (0.4)
2.8 (0.3)
3.0 (0.3)


Min - Max
2.3 - 4.4
2.0 - 3.4
2.2 - 3.8



Created on 2024-08-27 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for your quick and thorough response! I tested out your solution, and it worked with my data.
Remaining questions:
(1) The tbl_ard_summary errored when I included the original add_overall() line. Is there a way to add an overall column?
(2) Adding a "label = list(...)" argument from the original tbl_summary also errored. How can I work around this to add labels?
Note for others: I created a list of my 80+ categorical variables(E.g. all_categorical |> c(var1, var2, var3, etc.)), then replaced the ard_categorical line with ard_categorical(variables = all_of(all_categorical)).

The tbl_ard_*() frame work is brand new, and I am still building it out. At the moment it doesn't support all the function the tbl_summary() function supports. To get overall columns (for now), you 'd need to repeat the code above without the by variable, then you can use tbl_merge() to combine the two tables. There is no label argument now, but if you install the dev version of the gtsummary package, the label argument is there.

Instead of using the dev version of the pkg to get the label argument, you can also assign column labels before passing the data frame to ard_stack(). The easiest way to assign column labels is with the labelled::set_variable_labels() function IMO

I have yet to find method that is built into gtsummary. I was able to create a work around. Unfortunately, this is not very dynamic or universal; it's highly dependent on the arrangement in the table you used in your question. It will probably require modification to repurpose.
I created a function that modifies the table, per your request.
fixer <- function(tbl) {   # add row percentages to table with column percentages
  tabIn <- tbl$inputs
  nms <- names(tabIn$type[tabIn$type %in% "categorical"]) # which columns?
                           # calculate the row %, arrange/format as per table
  rp <- table(tabIn$data[, nms], tabIn$data[, tabIn[["by"]]]) %>% 
    prop.table(1) %>% t() %>% as.vector() %>% style_percent()
                           # add percentages to the table
  map(2:3, \(j) {                                # for each row in the table
    imap(paste0("stat_", 1:3), \(k, i) {         # for the stat in each row
      val <- tbl$table_body[[j, k]]              # collect content
      val2 <- str_replace(val, "\\)", paste0("/", rp[(j - 1) * i], "%\\)")) # fix
      tbl$table_body[[j, k]] <<- val2            # add update back to table
      })
    })
  tbl          # return updated table
  }

When you create your table or after calling your table, you call this function. For example:
iris_table %>% fixer()   # call table and update

Or with the table as it's made --
library(gtsummary)

iris_table <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length.Cat = if_else(Sepal.Length > 5, "Big","Small")) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              include = c(Sepal.Length.Cat, Sepal.Width),
              type = list(
                Sepal.Width ~ "continuous2"
              ),
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous2() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})","{min} - {max}"),
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"
              ),
              percent = "column",
              missing_text = "Missing") %>% 
  add_overall(col_label = "**Overall** <br>N = {n}") %>% 
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA) %>% fixer()   # <---- I'm new

Check it out


This function is really cool, thank you for all your hard work! I am attempting to modify for my actual data's table to see if it will work. My main sticking point it trying to figure out how to modify to include all 80+ categorical variables, each with different levels. I'm guessing it somewhere in the map(2:3...) part of the function (apologies, I am new to functions)?

No problem. In the table above, you've got three variables across and 2 variable rows. You see 2:3 in the first map call, those are the rows that are affected - (row 1 is that row with only the words Sepal. Length Cat). In the nested call to imap, you see stat_...., because each column with statistics is named stat_1, stat_2...and so on (where the overallis always and onlystat_0. If you look at iris_table$itable_bodyyou'll see that table as a data frame. (It may help.) If you have more questions, let me know. The call that createsrp` -- that should be seperate for ea. var
